# Using memory mapped buffers for scipy sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have to handle sparse matrix that can occasionally be very big, nearing or exceeding RAM capacity. I also need to support `mat*vec` and `mat*mat` operations.

Since internally a `csr_matrix` is 3 arrays `data`, `indices` and `indptr` is it possible to create a csr matrix from numpy memmap.

Comment: I don't see how it would work.  Access, for example to a row of the `csr` matrix requires getting a pair of values from the `indptr`, and using those to get a slice from each of the `data` and `indices` arrays.  And the matrix multiplication routines use a 2 step call to compiled code.  `sparse.save_npz` saves those 3 arrays to a `npz` archive, one array per file in the archive.

Comment: @hpaulj What problems do you anticipate in reading a pair of values from a memmapped `indptr` and getting a slice each from memmapped `data` and `indices`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This works without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work efficiently by doing these things:

- I dumped `data`, `indices` and `indptr` to binary files using `tobytes()`.
- I loaded an mmap object of each of those arrays.
- I made sure that the data types of `indices` and `indptr` are the same; otherwise one of them will be converted when you construct the `csr_matrix`.
- I explicitly provided the `shape` of the sparse matrix; otherwise the constructor will examine the array contents, which makes construction slow.
- Finally, and the most ad hoc thing on this list, I edited my local `scipy/sparse/_compressed.py` script to turn off `check_contents` (by setting it to `False`) in the call to `get_index_dtype()` in the matrix constructor.

I suspect the constructor would have succeeded without me editing the scipy source, but it was taking forever. With the above steps, loading a large mmapped sparse matrix is basically instantaneous, and I can perform the operations on it that I need to.

Answer (score 1):

This can partially work, until you try to do much with the array. There's a very good chance the subarrays will be fully read into memory if you subset, or you'll get an error.

An important consideration here is that the underlying code is written assuming the arrays are typical in-memory numpy arrays. Cost of random access is very different for mmapped arrays and in memory arrays. In fact, much of the code here is (at time of writing) in Cython, which may not be able to work with more exotic array types.

Also most of this code can change at any time, as long as the behaviour is the same for in-memory arrays. This has personally bitten me when some I learned some code I worked with was doing this, but with `h5py.Dataset`s for the underlying arrays. It worked surprisingly well, until a bug fix release of `scipy` completely broke it.